# Load balancer with custom routing rule implemented in Java?

Tags: java, load-balancing

I'm looking for a way to set up a simple load balancer with a custom routing rule implemented in Java. The custom routing rule is looking up the destination based on a cookie sent by the request. The destination must be retrieved on each request as it may change over time. Therefore, I can't generate static routing rules in advance.

I would prefer implementing the custom routing rule in Java as I already have all logic in place to figure out the destination based on the cookie. However, I can't find a load balancer allowing to plugin a custom routing rule implemented in Java. Any hints?

I don't want to implement a router in Java from scratch, but only provide the routing logic. Is that possible?

Comment: As your question relates to finding a piece of hardware to satisfy your needs (even if those needs are based on wishing to develop Java code), I've voted this as off-topic and suggest a repost on http://superuser.com/.

Comment: I'm not talking about hardware. I want to extend a software load balancer like http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html